# Launcher problems

Tags: applications

Somehow after turning off my tablet I lost my launcher.  Everything was working fine when I turned it off last night.  The only problem I have had was trying to set up a game called "High Five Casino Real Slots".  Now I can't even get to try anything before I get the message that my launcher hass sstpped working and then m screen goes black.  What the hell did I do? Marge Lines

Answer (score 0):

**How to Fix this problem:**

Boot into [safe mode](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info), uninstall the "High Five Casino Real Slots" or the app you think is causing the problem (probably also the launcher if it is a custom launcher) and reboot into your phone and see if your problem is fixed.

Once you have found out the problem you can install the apps that you uninstalled but that weren't the problem.